# Building tensorflow with different wheel name

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

Is it possible to build the Tensorflow Python wheel with a different name than tensorflow?

I would like to build Tensorflow with SIMD instructions like SSE, AVX and FMA and distribute that internally in our repository. I've managed to build it, but the package name is tensorflow. To keep the package separate from the official package, I would like to call it tensorflow-optimized or something similar.

Is this possible with the bazel build system?

Or is there a way I could edit the wheel?

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted, but if there is some missing information or anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not part of the bazel build system, it is part of the tensorflow project's script. I think the relevant line is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L44. So you should be able to pass `--project_name` to override it.